# Should I minimize the number of interfaces in a controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, domain-driven-design, ninject-2

In the below snip I have my controller which takes three interfaces. These are wired up via Ninject. Ok all great, definately a step in the right direction. My questions are this?

1.) Would it be better to wrap the 3 interfaces up in to one interface and a implement that way, thus reducing the amount of params passed to the ctor of the controller?
2.) Leave it alone, it is working?

I am always looking for ways to abstract the hell out of everything..
Thoughts?

```
public class RegistrationController : Controller
{
    private readonly ICategoriesService _categoriesService;
    private readonly IAuthenticationService _authenticationService;
    private readonly IRegistrationService _registrationService;

    // Ctor
    public RegistrationController(ICategoriesService categoriesService, 
        IAuthenticationService authenticationService,
        IRegistrationService registrationService)
    {
        _categoriesService = categoriesService;
        _authenticationService = authenticationService;
        _registrationService = registrationService;
    }
```

}

Comment: Overthinking everything but the title, I'd suggest :-) A good title is half the battle.

Comment: I was wondering why my title got changed, LOL... thanks man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a huge interface (or a huge class, which is what you'll need in order to implement a huge interface) because it is "convenient" is widely considered an [antipattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object). Based on the names of your current interfaces, they seem to be nicely and logically structured around what kind of operations they provide, and I suggest that you keep them that way (this also gives higher flexibility, since there may be other places where you only need some of the interfaces).

By the way: If you have proper unit tests and integration tests, "leave it alone, it's working" is a phrase that is never needed. ;-)

Comment: since I am anoob here it is making me wait 8mins to accept as an asnswer. Cool deal though, I will keep things as they are and continue. Thanks much, I apprecaite the fast response.

Comment: @Code Jammr: No problem; most answers aren't accepted nearly as fast anyway (and it is perfectly legitimate to wait for several answers to accumulate and then select the best one - in particular since the question is about code design, so that it is very possible that someone would have a counterpoint to my opinion). :-)